# How can I coerce a check for a variable being defined or not into a string reading True or False?

Tags: javascript

I have console logs set up like this:

```
console.log("getTestStatusActions" + this.userTestStatusActions === undefined);
```

This gives as an output the single word "False".

How can I make the output of this be:

```
"getTestStatusActions: userTestStatusActions defined"
```

or

```
"getTestStatusActions: userTestStatusActions undefined"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ternary!

```
console.log("getTestStatusActions" + (this.userTestStatusActions === undefined ? "undefined" : "defined"));
```

Or, for readability:

```
var status = this.userTestStatusActions === undefined ? "undefined" : "defined";
console.log("getTestStatusActions: userTestStatusActions " + status);
```